# Why is Typescript giving me an error in generic index signature

Tags: typescript, generics, method-signature

I have two types defined like this:

```
type Type1 = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type Type2 = 'D' | 'B' | 'F';
```

I have create 2 objects using these types like so:

```
const TYPE1 : { [ id in Type1 ] : {
  label : string;
  image : string;
} } = {
  A: {
    label: 'a',
    image: 'a.jpg',
  },
  B: {
    label: 'b',
    image: 'b.png',
  },
  C: {
    label: 'c',
    image: 'c.gif',
  },
};

const TYPE2 : { [ id in Type2 ] : {
  label : string;
  image : string;
  val : number;
} } = {
  D: {
    label: 'd',
    image: 'd.jpg',
    val: 0,
  },
  B: {
    label: 'b',
    image: 'b.png',
    val: 1,
  },
  F: {
    label: 'f',
    image: 'f.gif',
    val: 2,
  },
};
```

Since these 2 objects are very similar I want to create a generic function that can operate on both, so I was hoping to do this:

```
function doStuff<T>( typeIn : {[key in T] : { label : string; image : string } } ) {
  // use T here for stuff 
}
```

This doesn't work as I'm getting the following error:

**Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.(2322)**

I can make the function work if I change the function signature to:

```
function doStuff( typeIn : {[key : string] : { label : string; image : string } } ) {
  //oh oh, I no longer know if typeIn is using Type1 or Type2
}
```

Is there a way I can declare typeIn using the generic T?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you are not [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) your generic type `T` to something the compiler recognizes as key-like.  You can use `PropertyKey` (which is a synonym for `string | number | symbol`) and the error will go away:

```
function doStuff<T extends PropertyKey>(
  typeIn: { [key in T]: { label: string; image: string } }
) { }
```

And you can call `doStuff()` as you intend:

```
doStuff(TYPE1); // T is inferred as Type1
doStuff(TYPE2); // T is inferred as Type2
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEYoF4oHICCaoB90CFs80BhNAbgChRJZ4AmFdAESILbQDELLKBjAPYA7AM7BYATQAKAUQQAuKAG8oAbQCWAEyjqhdSAgC6ipZSjmoAGwCGAIwiXFYgE66A5lQs6AttbcQnYFchD0oAXygI1FMvDBMzLwsbe0d0azQAGgTEnz8AtIA6ACswN0zsyKyvfHic82SHRTRbcrrc-ybbArAQ1oswqosSWrqG1LQ+Ppz1Xw70PgK3dQAzKcrwqn5hMUlZehM1LR09OEh6Y2UKscDgjygKmbyb908LADdrVKEAV297ZyoESily8zBGOWu6E0ay8jzmaE0xVKMPen0UAAZBuYBhUaiDRnZGugWljEnD8s1ur1SV4PqkEKScV5OODEpC0KsaRZyU1losVijzHTFPRGVkwptlt8hHxgOphFBNAIAMrAb7LZYAHhgUAgAA9gBAhJoRFApM4BJBnKAANIQEAAPgAFDQIABJIQHVQAa3tx1gFxUkJcL3a+RDIUikQAlMpIrwlar1csnTBpHJo+QoAB6bOwHSm3TLCDOZwQbTWU2nRCURNqjWp9P0TM5vM69SFoTF0vlqCV-QQehAA)